# An example of topological space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X=${$a,b,c$} be a set. Let $z=${$\emptyset$, {$a$}, $X$} be a set. Is the set $z$ a topological space on $X$?

[*Recall: definition of topological space*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TopologicalSpace.html).

My trying: We know that $P(X)=${$\emptyset$, {$a$},{$b$},{$c$},{$a,b$},{$a,c$},{$b,c$},$X$} and $z\subset P(X)$.

- $\emptyset$, $X$ in $z$, clear.
- ''The intersection of finite collection of sets in $z$ is also in $z$'' I couldn't show this.
- The union of any collection of sets in $z$ is also in $z$ç

**How can I show last two properties, can you help?**

Comment: Check all the possible cases.

Comment: Either you see it at first glance (as you should), or there are $8$ - actually, $5$ - unions and $8$ - actually, $5$ - intersections for you to check.

Comment: So, to do ''the union of any collection of sets in zz is also in zz'', how many are there cases?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that if you take two elements of $z$ then their intersection is also in $z$. To do this you need to check $3$ cases.

Comment: 3 cases, why?..

Comment: So, to do ''the union of any collection of sets in $z$ is also in $z$'', how many are there cases?

Comment: also $3$, when the ground set is finite it suffices to check finite intersections.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to take account to the power set? For the intersection, brutal force: $\emptyset\cap X=\emptyset$, $\emptyset\cap\{a\}=\emptyset$, $\{a\}\cap X=\{a\}$.

Comment: Thanks, for answer.

Comment: So, to do ''the union of any collection of sets in zz is also in zz'', how many are there cases?

Comment: $\emptyset$, $\{a\}$, $X$, $\emptyset\cup\{a\}$, $\emptyset\cup X$, $\{a\}\cup X$, $\emptyset\cup\{a\}\cup X$. You know, there is a standard combinatoric technique dealing with the ways of such choices.